# Exception thrown from event handler in newrelic_agent_*.log

Tags: windows, iis, newrelic

There are errors is NewRelic logs:

```
...
2014-03-28 13:35:14,167 NewRelic INFO: Harvest starting
2014-03-28 13:35:15,136 NewRelic INFO: Harvest starting
2014-03-28 13:35:20,355 NewRelic INFO: Harvest starting
2014-03-28 13:35:23,543 NewRelic ERROR: Exception thrown from event handler.  Event handlers should not let exceptions bubble out of them.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NewRelic.Agent.Core.Metric.StatsMap`1.Merge(T name, IStats newStats)
   at NewRelic.Agent.Core.Metric.StatsMap`1.Merge(IStatsMap`1 otherMap)
   at NewRelic.Agent.Core.Metric.StatsCollection.RecordTransactionStats(String scope, ITransactionStats txStats)
   at NewRelic.Agent.Core.Utilities.EventBus`1.Publish(T message)
2014-03-28 13:35:33,090 NewRelic INFO: Harvest starting
2014-03-28 13:36:07,575 NewRelic INFO: Harvest starting
...
```

Windows Events log not contain any records about this.

OS Windows 2012

Status monitor show "New Relic has not sent data" for this application. however, the protocols have an records of sending data.

Anybody know about this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue causing this error was fixed in version 2.22.79.0 of the .Net Agent so if you are running an older version upgrading should fix the problem.